# Properties file on Travis CI

Tags: android, github, travis-ci

I am building an **Github Android project** using **Travis-CI** however I have some files which have secret data which I don't want to upload it to GitHub (As it is open and anyone can view it).
In my build.gradle I have written code to load the *.properties file and extract values from it and I have not uploaded these properties files onto GitHub but I want that my properties files should be received when Travis-CI build is being made.
Is there any way I can do this?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Encrypt your file(s). The process is explained in https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/encrypting-files